# Rails: can`t get data in callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to modify data before validation, but can't: by using `self.param_name` will be returned `nil`. My code:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation do
        logger.info ":category_parameters before: #{self.category_parameters}"
        self.category_parameters = self.category_parameters.split(/,/)
        logger.info ":category_parameters after: #{self.category_parameters}"
    end
end
```

Log file:

```
Started PATCH "/categories/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-16 15:13:15 +0300
Processing by CategoriesController#update as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7RswlNAVs26W72IY6eL56xmACbVPCZQvl7MqDMueUbg=", "category"=>{"name"=>"Computers", "url"=>"computers", "category_parameters"=>"gergewrg,rewgwerg,wergwerg"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"9"}
    Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
:category_parameters before: []
:category_parameters after: [[]]
```

I use PostgreSQL and `:category_parameters` have type `array` in my schema:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "category_parameters",     array: true
    ...
end
```

## UPD:

Controller code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    ...

    def edit
    end

    ...

    def update
        respond_to do |format|

            if @category.update(category_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    ...

    private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:name, :url, :category_parameters)
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you permitting the `category_parameters` attribute through `strong_params`?

Comment: Yes, of course: `params.require(:category).permit(:name, :url, :category_parameters)`. And in log file i don`t see warning about permissions

Comment: You mention `before_validation` - have you tried any other hook, like `before_save`?

Comment: Can you post your strong params method?

Comment: Controller added in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59449/discussion-between-cannyfoxx-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reserved**

After talking on chat, it appears the original attribute name of `category_parameters` was reserved by Rails for some reason (hence why the OP couldn't populate it).

The fix was to change the attribute name in the db to `nested_params`, the `strong_params` reference, and finally the attributes in the view. Here is the result:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7RswlNAVs26W72IY6eL56xmACbVPCZQvl7MqDMueUbg=", "category"=>{"name"=>"Computers", "url"=>"computers", "nested_params"=>"{123,123,123},{123,gwehrewrh,235235}"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"9"}
:nested_params before: ["123", "123", "123", "123", "gwehrewrh", "235235"] 
:nested_params after: [["123", "123", "123", "123", "gwehrewrh", "235235"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe should create a list of reserved methods like in Java. I will send offer to github

Answer (score 0):

Changing your strong parameters to this format should solve your problem.

```
def category_params
  params[:category][:category_parameters] = params[:category][:category_parameters].split!(',')
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :url, :category_parameters => [])
end
```

Comment: User send me data with text type. On server i will parse text to array. It`s not a "cure"

Comment: Oh i c my mistake, well i have another suggestion. Why not convert it to an array in the controller itself. The conversion is not a validation so moving that conversion to the controller or before_save block would make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `category_parameters` are not being passed as an array, they're being passed as a string.

You could try this...

```
params[:category][:category_parameters] = params[:category][:category_parameters].split(/,/)
params.require(:category).permit(:name, :url, category_parameters: [])
```

Do NOT do a before_validation record, as it will mess up your record every time you re-save it for any reason.

Comment: In log file: `Unpermitted parameters: category_parameters` and error `NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes, mistake in my first line, now corrected. If you try again with my revised code, it should work this time.

Comment: YEs, sorry, error in my first line.  Also, I'm now inclined to suggest you do NOT do this on `before_validation` as every time you retrieve and resave the record you will mess up your category_parameters